# Django 3.1 No reverse match at / not a registered namespace error

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm following an old guide about online store design in `django` and i faced a weird problem using reverse function inside one of my apps model file. This is the general structure of my project:

```
shop(main project)
 |-myshop(preview of general website pages)
 |-utility(some utilities and context processors)
 |-catalog(catalog related modules of the website)
 |-cart(shopping cart module)
 |-manage.py
 |-db.sqlite3
```

These are my error related files of project:
main `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from myshop import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home_view),
    path('signup/', views.signup_view, name="signup"),
    path('sent/', views.activation_sent_view, name="activation_sent"),
    path('activate/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>/', views.activate, name='activate'),
    path('signin/', views.signin_view, name="signin"),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path('catalog/', include(('catalog.urls', 'catalog'), namespace='catalog')),
]
```

catalog `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from catalog import views

app_name = 'catalog'

urlpatterns = [
   re_path(r'^$', views.home_view, name='catalog_home'),   
   re_path(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.show_category, name='catalog_category'),    
   re_path(r'^product/(?P<product_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.show_product, name='catalog_product'),
]
```

catalog `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):      
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)      
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True,
        help_text='Unique value for product page URL, created from name.')      
    description = models.TextField()      
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)      
    meta_keywords = models.CharField("Meta Keywords", max_length=255,help_text='Comma-delimited set of SEO keywords for meta tag')
    meta_description = models.CharField("Meta Description", max_length=255, help_text='Content for description meta tag')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)      
    
    class Meta:           
        db_table = 'categories'           
        ordering = ['-created_at']           
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'      
        
    def __unicode__(self):           
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):           
        return reverse('catalog:catalog_category', (), { 'category_slug': self.slug }, current_app='catalog')
```

This is the template tries to retrieve absolute link with reverse function:

```
<h3>Categories</h3> 
{% for c in active_categories %}      
<a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}"></a>{{ c.name }}</a><br /> 
{% endfor %}
```

And catalogs are available through a custom context processor:

```
from catalog.models import Category 
from shop import settings 

def shop(request):      
    return {
        'active_categories': Category.objects.filter(is_active=True),
        'site_name': settings.SITE_NAME,           
        'meta_keywords': settings.META_KEYWORDS,           
        'meta_description': settings.META_DESCRIPTION,           
        'request': request}
```

I already tried to fix the issue with some stack answered questions about namespace registering and i failed. I still getting this error with runserver:

```
NoReverseMatch at /

'catalog' is not a registered namespace
```

What's wrong i'm doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None)
```

You shouldn't pass empty set `()` to urlconf in reverse function, delete it

```py
def get_absolute_url(self):
   return reverse('catalog:catalog_category', kwargs={ 'category_slug': self.slug }, current_app='catalog')
```

Comment: Oh well noted. when i remove the empty set the error changes to unhashable type dict. 
It seems i can't also pass slug argument as dictionary. After some search about reverse i found that it should be passed like this: `kwargs = { 'category_slug': self.slug }` , so i edit your answer to the perfect form.